# "Cannot convert parameter 1 from double to float" although didn't change parameters

Tags: c++

As a beginner in coding I am preparating for my C exam and was doing one excercise where I had to write a programm which should calculate sinh x... When I wrote in a normal way it worked properly and calculated the right answers, but when I changed my function from Call by value to Call by reference, I got a mistake "Cannot convert parameter 1 from double to float"... Why did I got it and what shall I consider when I use that value? 
Here you can see my code :)

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "iostream"
float e=2.71828;
using namespace std;


float sinhyp (float *x)
{

    return (0.5*(pow(e,*x)-pow(e,(-1)*(*x))));


}



int _tmain(void)
{

        float erg=sinhyp(15.0);
        printf("%f \n", erg);


    system ("Pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for the advices / help ;)

Comment: Are you using C or C++? `using namespace std;` is an invalid statement in C, and the `iostream` header is not usable in C.

Comment: I have a small side bet here that the posted error "Cannot convert parameter 1 from double to float" is really "Cannot convert parameter 1 from double to float *"  (note added `*`)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `stdafx.h` header isn't in either C or C++...

Comment: @TobySpeight It is a header commonly used in VC++. It's not part of any standard library.

Answer (score 6):

C doesn't have call by reference. When you change a function parameter's type from `float` to `float *`, you must change the caller to match. Your function now requires a pointer, so you must provide a pointer. For example, this call would work:

```
float fifteen = 15.0;
float erg=sinhyp(&fifteen);
```

The `&` operator is the key. It produces a pointer value, pointing to the variable that contains the value `15.0`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, still the code wasn't accepted

Answer (score 1):

15.0 is a double constant.

Try making it a float constant instead

**15.0f**

Comment: Hmmm, with this idea I get "error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'sinhyp'". Neither `15.0` not `15.0f` are valid `float *`.

Comment: yep. float * is something different.  Break open a book, and study pointers in c.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is expecting a `float *`, but you're passing it a `double`.  You can't convert between pointers and values that way.

Since your function doesn't actually change the value that's passed in, you don't need a pointer.  Then the value `15.0`, which is a `double`, can be safely converted to a `float`:

```
float sinhyp (float x)
{
    return (0.5*(pow(e,x)-pow(e,(-1)*(x))));
}
```

Comment: Okay :) Thank you very much .... It was strange cause one of the excercises expected me to change it so I wasn't sure :) Will try it out now :)

Answer (score 1):

`float sinhyp (float *x)` is not a pass by *reference*.  It is passing by *value* a `float *` or [pointer to float](https://cdecl.org/?q=float+*x).

To pass by *reference* use `&`.

```
// float sinhyp (float *x) {
float sinhyp (float &x) {
    // return (0.5*(pow(e,*x)-pow(e,(-1)*(*x))));
    return (0.5*(pow(e,x)-pow(e,(-1)*(x))));
}
```

Call with the matching type

```
    // float erg=sinhyp(15.0);
    float erg=sinhyp(15.0f);
```

Comment: When I changed it that way got the error: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'double' to 'float &'

Comment: @SansaStark Did you code `sinhyp(15.0);` or `sinhyp(15.0f);` as per this answer?  (Notice the `f`)